# Nesting several groups of columns inside a data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

The concept of nesting several columns into a single list-column is very powerful. However, I am not sure whether it is possible at all to nest more than one set of columns into several list-columns within the same pipeline using the `nest` function in `{tidyr}`. For instance, assume I have the following data frame:

```
df <- as.data.frame(replicate(6, runif(10) * 100))

colnames(df) <- c(
    paste0("a", 1:2), # a1, a2
    paste0("b", 1:4) # b1, b2, b3, b4
)

df
          a1        a2        b1       b2        b3        b4
1  20.807348 69.339482 91.837151 99.76813  3.394350 33.780049
2  64.667733 20.676381 80.523369 38.42774 85.635208 60.111491
3  55.352501 55.699571  4.812923 38.65333 98.869203 80.345576
4  45.194094 16.511696 83.834651 51.48698  7.191081 16.697210
5  66.401642 89.041055 26.965636 67.90061 90.622428 59.552935
6  35.750100 55.997766 49.768556 68.45900 67.523080 58.993232
7  21.392823  5.335281 56.348328 35.68331 51.029617 66.290035
8   8.851236 19.486580 14.199370 22.49754 14.617592 18.236406
9  70.475652  6.229997 43.169364 12.63378 21.415589  2.163004
10 47.837613 37.641530 38.001288 71.15896 71.000568  2.135611
```

I would like to nest the "a" columns into a list-column AND nest the "b" columns into a second list-column because I would like to perform different computations on them.

Nesting the "a" columns works:

```
library(tidyr)
nest(df, a1, a2, .key = "a")

          b1       b2        b3        b4                   a
1  91.837151 99.76813  3.394350 33.780049  20.80735, 69.33948
2  80.523369 38.42774 85.635208 60.111491  64.66773, 20.67638
3   4.812923 38.65333 98.869203 80.345576  55.35250, 55.69957
4  83.834651 51.48698  7.191081 16.697210  45.19409, 16.51170
5  26.965636 67.90061 90.622428 59.552935  66.40164, 89.04105
6  49.768556 68.45900 67.523080 58.993232  35.75010, 55.99777
7  56.348328 35.68331 51.029617 66.290035 21.392823, 5.335281
8  14.199370 22.49754 14.617592 18.236406 8.851236, 19.486580
9  43.169364 12.63378 21.415589  2.163004 70.475652, 6.229997
10 38.001288 71.15896 71.000568  2.135611  47.83761, 37.64153
```

But it is impossible to nest the "b" columns AFTER the "a" columns have been nested:

```
nest(df, a1, a2, .key = "a") %>%
    nest(b1, b2, b3, b4, .key = "b")
Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
  Column `a` can't be used as a grouping variable because it's a list
```

which makes sense by reading the error message.

My work-around is to:

- nest the "a" columns
- perform the required computations on the "a" list-column
- unnest the "a" list-column
- nest the "b" columns
- perform the required computations on the "b" list-column
- unnest the "b" list-column

Is there a more straight-forward way to achieve this? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Would you want to gather the data into a long format, so you have an "a" column and a "b" column, and nest by groups that way? I'm having a little trouble picturing what you're after

Comment: @camille Yes, your solution would work normally, but not just in my case. "a" and "b" are "tests" and "homework" and my goal is to drop the lowest score of each evaluation type. So I want to first nest them into 1-row data frames and sort them this way before calculating the final grade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `map` to do this

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- list('a', 'b') %>% 
           map(~ df %>% 
            select(matches(.x)) %>% 
            nest(names(.), .key = !! rlang::sym(.x))) %>%
            bind_cols
out
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  a                     b                    
#  <list>                <list>               
#1 <data.frame [10 × 2]> <data.frame [10 × 4]>


out %>%
   unnest
# A tibble: 10 x 6
#      a1    a2    b1    b2    b3    b4
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 20.8  69.3  91.8   99.8  3.39 33.8 
# 2 64.7  20.7  80.5   38.4 85.6  60.1 
# 3 55.4  55.7   4.81  38.7 98.9  80.3 
# 4 45.2  16.5  83.8   51.5  7.19 16.7 
# 5 66.4  89.0  27.0   67.9 90.6  59.6 
# 6 35.8  56.0  49.8   68.5 67.5  59.0 
# 7 21.4   5.34 56.3   35.7 51.0  66.3 
# 8  8.85 19.5  14.2   22.5 14.6  18.2 
# 9 70.5   6.23 43.2   12.6 21.4   2.16
#10 47.8  37.6  38.0   71.2 71.0   2.14
```

We could do the separate computations on the 'a' and 'b' list of columns

```
out %>%
    mutate(a = map(a, `*`, 4)) %>% 
    unnest
# A tibble: 10 x 6
#      a1    a2    b1    b2    b3    b4
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  83.2 277.  91.8   99.8  3.39 33.8 
# 2 259.   82.7 80.5   38.4 85.6  60.1 
# 3 221.  223.   4.81  38.7 98.9  80.3 
# 4 181.   66.0 83.8   51.5  7.19 16.7 
# 5 266.  356.  27.0   67.9 90.6  59.6 
# 6 143.  224.  49.8   68.5 67.5  59.0 
# 7  85.6  21.3 56.3   35.7 51.0  66.3 
# 8  35.4  77.9 14.2   22.5 14.6  18.2 
# 9 282.   24.9 43.2   12.6 21.4   2.16
#10 191.  151.  38.0   71.2 71.0   2.14
```

Having said that, it is also possible to select columns of interest with `mutate_at` instead of doing `nest/unnest`

```
df %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(matches('^a\\d+')), funs(.*4))
```